# Unable to boot Grub2 using UNetbootin

Tags: windows-7, liveusb, unetbootin

I downloaded the ISO files for [Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/) as well as a usb-live creator [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). After an apparent successful write to USB, a restart does not elicit a boot. I have checked my BIOS settings to ensure External Device was selected as the highest priority.

Is there any reason this may not be working?

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of different explanations for this faulty behavior.

1. Your BIOS has *Secure Boot* enabled. You deal with this by disabling it altogether.
2. Your BIOS is set on UEFI, while you have your iso image set for BIOS (legacy) boot. Or vice versa. Again, you deal with this by checking that the two are compatible, either by changing the BIOS settings, or by changing the iso image.
3. Unetbootin produced an unbootable stick. This occurs because it overwrites the syslinux.cfg. Some boot disks leave the standard version unaltered, so they can boot without any problems, but other distros modify the syslinux.cfg file to suit their needs, and these will not boot properly from a USB stick produced with Unetbootin. I know nothing about your specific case, but, should you be willing to try alternative methods for Windows, you can find [on the Arch Wiki page on USB Flash installation methods](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Flash_Installation_Media#In_Windows) an excellent discussion of several easily accessible possibilities.

These are standard sources of error. If this does not fix your problem, you will have to provide some more data for the diagnosis.